# How to enlarge the media file upload size in wordpress admin

Tags: php, uploads

I'm using wordpress 3.0 with buddypress.

I need to enlarge the file size that is being uploaded from the media section in the admin menu.

We have tried many ways including the methods from this [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/) but nothing made it larger than a 1 mega.

Is there a different way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Where is your website hosted ? Did you check with your hosting company ?

Comment: As Mike says it could be down to your host... you can make as may changes as you like but they may ultimately control the size of file uploads.

Comment: The server is local, we have full control over it. other wordpress sites are installed on it and each and every one of them shows a different upload size, some 1 others 2. what should be done on the server except the info that we've written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using multisite make sure you set "Max upload file size" to some higher limit.

> Network Admin -> Settings -> Network settings -> Upload settings ->
>   Max upload file size